# Уезжают картинки в таблице под текст

Tags: html, css, table

Почему картинки уезжают вниз, если места достаточно, отступов лишних нет, все помещается?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

HTML код:
(первые два дива общие с сайта, никак не мешают)

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="maxwidth">
            <div class="socseti">
                    <div class="socseti-block">
                        <div class="socsetitext">
                            <h3>Instagram</h3>
                            <p>Подписывайтесь на наш канал, в котором много полезной информации.<br>Отсканируйте QR-код</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pngseti">
                            <img src="/upload/inst-code.png";>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="socseti-block">
                        <div class="socsetitext"> 
                            <h3>Youtube</h3>
                            <p>Подписывайтесь на наш канал, в котором много полезной информации.<br>Отсканируйте QR-код</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pngseti">
                            <img src="/upload/yt-code.png">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="socseti-block">
                        <div class="socsetitext">
                            <h3>Telegram</h3>
                            <p>Подписывайтесь на наш канал, в котором много полезной информации.<br>Отсканируйте QR-код</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pngseti">
                            <img src="/upload/tel-code.png">
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.socseti {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.socsetitext
{
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 20px;
  width:50%;
  padding:20px;
}
.pngseti {
  align-items: right;
  float:right;
  padding-right:20px;
}
.socseti-background {
    background-color:white;
    width:90%;
}
.socseti-block {
    width:25%;
    background-color:#cce6e4;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-right:20px;
```

Comment: Потому что `div.pngseti` -- блочный элемент

Answer (score 0):

если уж начал в флексах то и продолжим:

```
.socseti-block {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

у .pngseti убери align-items и float. лишнее